# In altair, delete extra grid space

Tags: python, altair, vega

Given the following code:

```
background = alt.Chart(pd.DataFrame({'start': [0, 6, 14, 20],'end': [6, 14, 20, 23],'time_of_day':['NIGHT','MORNING','AFTERNOON','NIGHT']})).mark_rect().encode(
    x=alt.X('start:O'),
    x2='end:O',
    color=alt.Color('time_of_day:N', scale=alt.Scale(domain=['NIGHT', 'MORNING', 'AFTERNOON', 'NIGHT'],
                                                     range(['lightblue','orange','lightgreen','lightblue'])),
    opacity=alt.value(0.4)  # Adjust the opacity as needed
)
```

I got the following output:

[image]

I want to delete the extra gridspace before 0 and after the 23.

Does anyone know how to do so?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `chart.configure_view(stroke=None)` as in https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/customization.html#removing-the-chart-border